# Fixed Position Header Div Centered With 80% Width

Tags: css

I tried to create a div as a header bar and failed.
I want the div will be fixed, centered and 80% width.

Code :

```
#header {
position: fixed;
display: inline-block;
/*left: 0px*/
top: 0px;
margin: auto;
width: 80%;
height : 175px;
border: 1px solid black;
}
```

HTML Code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title> Yakir Freed </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

    <div id="header">
        <img id="logo" src="images/logo.png" alt="Yakir Freed" />
    </div>
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

Comment: Share also your HTML. Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please look at guide [how do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I don't understand why do you need the rest of the code. Additionally I can't edit the post and add more code.
BTW the html code is total of 11 lines. And most of it is rows

Comment: Without HTML we can't help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this out:

```css
#header {
position: fixed;
display: inline-block;
left: 0px;
top: 0px;
margin: 0 10%;
width: 80%;
height : 175px;
border: 1px solid black;

}
```

```html
<div id="header"></div>
```

Comment: Great !
Can you explain to me the logic behind?

Comment: Yep, with width set to 80% and the margin on both sides set to 10% it will be centered. A complete guide to center certain content read this: https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/ . For `left: 0px` is used so the margin will hit the left side certainly. I forgot placing a semicolon behind `left: 0px` i'll edit my answer. Change it in your code if you already copied it.

Comment: OK, Thank you. My main problem is the lack of knowledge about CSS properties like display, posiotins, float, etc. I will be glad if you can give me a link to guide for begginers that learn that. :)

Comment: I've not tried this one but it looks decent: https://www.codecademy.com/en/tracks/htmlcss